# Changing font size of contentsname without changing it font size in fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, fancyhdr

How to change the font size of the content title without changing its size in the header

For example, I write in code "\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\huge Table of contents}" and I receive
[image]

in the same in header I have

[image]

How to work with them separately? Change the size of the header without changing the name? In all other text, my header is lowercase, italic and the same size as the text.

Sorry for my english, and thanks for your answer

Comment: `\.....name` macros should only have text, never any formatting

Comment: And how then change it size? All problems began when I rename TOC. I work in Book class

Comment: the formatting of section headings is specified by the class, you can modify that directly or via one of the packages for that.